# Setting permissions for user details page?

Tags: permissions

I am looking to use the User Details page, which shows the entire list of users and groups, plus some information relative to the user. I have set it up to look like a printable phone list.

My issue is that I am the only one who can see the page, is there a way to give read permission to the rest of the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer

1. Go to
   `https://yourdomain/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0`
2. click settings

you can edit the list permissions under there which will then give whomever access to the list and page.